# How to parallelize this C program?

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I want to parallelize the recursive calling of Fibonacci function.
How do I do this? This program is not just about computing fibonacci. I have to print the number of 0s and 1s generated after each test case N.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int n);

int ze = 0, on=0;

int main() {

    int i, T, N[41];
    scanf("%d", &T);
    if (T < 1 || T > 50)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &N[i]);
        if (N[i] < 0 || N[i] > 40)
            return 0;
    } 

    for (i = 0; i < T; i++, ze = 0, on = 0) {
        fibonacci(N[i]);
        printf("%d %d\n", ze, on);
    }
} 

int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        ze += 1;
        return 0; 
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        on += 1;
        return 1;
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Parallelizer - `printf("finger%d", (fibonacci(6)-2))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about parallel processing or multi-threading, so it would be nice to have such an answer for me as well.

However, in the mean time, you can resolve your problem by out-smarting it. You say that the purpose is not just to calculate the fibonacci numbers, but in the end the outcome is nothing but two fibonacci numbers, one being one order behind the other.

Specifically, `ze` is the fibonacci number of order `x - 1` and `on` is the fibonacci number of order `x`.

This is evident as *hell*, I must say, for the `on`, since it is the count of one's in the number. `ze`, on the other hand, is like that, because of the way you defined the function.

So, you could pre-calculate the flrst 40 fibonacci numbers in a more efficient way, and then use them. You could actuall go as high as ~90 if you want. Calculating first 40~90 fibonacci numbers should happen within a snap.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that **ze** from *zero* and **on** from *one* concatenates into ***zeon***? I don't think so.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. Please help to keep the quality of this site up and avoid such things.

Comment: @JensGustedt *This **is** an [answer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=answer).* It offers a solution to an implied problem (2a), although it didn't have to even do that (1a) to be an answer. Correct me if we are still in disagreement.